# Parse path string

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

Suppose path string are encoded in this way:

- 2T3T5: means move 2 steps, turn right, move 3 steps, turn right, and move 5 steps
- 32T: which better read as 3(2T), and it means do the following operation 3 times => (move 2 steps, turn right), if written in a complete word, it means move 2 steps, turn right, move 2 steps, turn right, move 2 steps, turn right
- 3(4T2T)5T, which means do 3 time operation of (move 4 steps, turn right, move 2 steps, turn right), then move 5 steps and turn right

The method I want to review is `parse_path`, and I put some other mock methods for debug purpose only. Any advice to make parser more reliable, more elegant/shorter and any code style advice is highly appreciated.

```
class Movement:
    def __init__(self,x,y,delta_x,delta_y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.delta_x = delta_x
        self.delta_y = delta_y
    def move(self, steps):
        print 'move ', steps
    def turn_right(self):
        print 'turn right'
    def parse_path(self, source):
        #2T3T5
        #32T
        #3(4T2T)5T
        start = 0
        index = 0
        while index < len(source):
            if source[index] == 'T':
                steps = int(source[start:index])
                if steps >= 10:
                    times = steps / 10
                    steps = steps % 10
                else:
                    times = 1
                for t in range(times):
                    self.move(steps)
                    self.turn_right()
                start = index + 1
                index += 1
            elif index == len(source) - 1:
                steps = int(source[start:index+1])
                if steps >= 10:
                    times = steps / 10
                    steps = steps % 10
                else:
                    times = 1
                for t in range(times):
                    self.move(steps)
                start = index + 1
                index += 1
            elif source[index] == '(':
                right = index
                while source[right] != ')':
                    right += 1
                times = int(source[start:index])
                for t in range(times):
                    self.parse_path(source[index+1:right])
                index = right + 1
                start = index
            else:
                index += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = Movement(0,0,0,0)
    # 2T3T5
    # 32T
    # 3(4T2T)5T
    #m.parse_path("2T3T5")
    #m.parse_path("32T")
    m.parse_path("3(4T2T)5T")
```

Comment: How should `999T` be parsed? `99(9T)`, `9(99T)` or `9(9(9T))`?

Comment: It is parsed as 99(9T). But is it a good design choice to have the times/steps like this? In my opinion, no!  To get 13 steps and a turn, you'll have to write 131T...

Comment: @MathiasEttinger,  holroy is correct.

Comment: @holroy, you are correct, if you have any advice to my original question on code review, it will be great.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, BTW, if you have any advice on my original question, it will be great.

Comment: I hope to get around to answering this tomorrow, or the day after, but I've been kind of busy lately.

Comment: @holroy No, worse, 13 steps and a turn is `(121)1T` or `(8)5T` since `131T` is 13 steps and 13 turns (`13(1T)`).

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, I was indeed wrong, but it turns out you are wrong as well. Neither `(121)1T` nor `(8)5T` works, but `1(121)1T` or `1(8)5T` does work... :-D

Comment: @holroy, thx and looking forward to learning from you.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, why 13 steps and a turn is (121)1T? Could you explain?

Comment: @holroy, why 13 steps and a turn is 1(121)1T or 1(8)5T? Could you explain?

Comment: @LinMa you can't use `131T` to make 13 steps and a turn as it is parsed as 13 times one step + one turn. So you have to make 12 steps before 1 step and a turn. Or 8 steps before 5 steps and a turn. It turns out that you require a multiplier before parenthesis, hence `1(121)1T` or `1(8)5T`. Which seems incredibly difficult to grasp for such a simple task (even you who wrote the code have troubles it seems). To me this code is broken by design.

Comment: Could you please enlighten us as to the origin of your path strings? Have you designed this yourself, is it someone else design? And what do you use it for? Please add a little section on the bottom to explain this.

Comment: The "13 steps and a turn" was an edge case I saw would be a little hard to do in your current design. So it's just a device to illustrate a point related to the chosen algorithm.